# Creating a numpy array from a .csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

Given a .csv file that look like this:

```
49.18;-3.34
45.73;2.63
47.88;-11.49
45.74;3.06
48.73;-9.56
49.20;-3.42
```

I use the following code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("file.csv",  delimiter=';')
```

And the resulting array looks like this:

```
[[ 49.18  -3.34]
 [ 45.73   2.63]
 [ 47.88 -11.49]
 [ 45.74   3.06]
 [ 48.73  -9.56]
 [ 49.2   -3.42]
 [ 45.71   2.53]
 [ 47.87 -11.67]]
```

But what I want is this:

```
 [[ 49.18 , -3.34]
 [ 45.73 ,  2.63]
 [ 47.88 , -11.49]
 [ 45.74 ,  3.06]
 [ 48.73 , -9.56]
 [ 49.2  , -3.42]
 [ 45.71 ,  2.53]
 [ 47.87 , -11.67]]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot, and I hope you can help me

Comment: Everything is fine. The print form of numpy doesn't shows the comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output of

```
data.shape
```

I believe it is already working as you wish.

Comment: This is the output: (125L, 2L)

Comment: So, 125 rows by 2 columns?

Is the problem that you want it to print a certain way or that you want it in a numpy array to work with?

Is type(data) an numpy.ndarray?

Comment: That's right, it's 125 rows and 2 columns. The problem is that I cannot access the columns separately using indexes. It is a numpy.ndarray

Comment: Please provide an example the indexing and the error it produces.

data[:,0] should access the first column

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an array instead of a numpy-array, then you can convert your `np.array` to a list with `tolist()`:

```
my_list = data.tolist()
```

Please remember that with a list you only can index every dimension with following notation:

```
print my_list[0][0]
```

and with a numpy-array you can use both notations:

```
print data[0,0]
print data[0][0]
```

Comment: `tolist()` produces a `list`, not an array.  Or rather a list of lists.  Python has a separate class called `array`.  But with the wide availability of `numpy`, that is rarely used.  I know I'm being picky, but terminology does matter when programming.